# Rendering attribute with two different formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object that has an attribute using a markdown language for the past few years and recently the attribute is now switched to using html. How do I render all the past campaign descriptions with the markup language and how do I render all the new campaign descriptions with .html_safe

Html_safe

```
<h6 class="text-muted" itemprop="description">
    <%= @campaign.product_description.html_safe %>
</h6>
```

Markdown

```
<h6 class="text-muted" itemprop="description">
  <%= Campaign::Format @campaign.product_description, {render_html: true} %>
</h6>
```

How can I render both? That way For all the old campaigns it renders the markup and for the new campaigns it renders the html. When I include html_safe and the markdown on the same line it only does the markup and not the html from a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

1. Add a flag to your campaigns. Something like `uses_html_description`. Set its values correspondingly. And switch on that in the view.
2. Do a data migration and replace all descriptions in old format with the new html format.

Between these two, I'd go with the latter.

Comment: Why would you prefer option 2? Option 1 seems easier.

Comment: @RonnieWiesenhower: does it though? The essential amount of work is the same, you have to walk all records and do something (set flag value or change description). But with option 1 your views are more complicated and your db has one extra column (which you have to deploy first. Depending on your db size, this likely means some downtime)

Comment: I see the upside to it. This may be a whole new question in itself. How can I convert the markdown to html. I put some of the markdown into this [online tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/markdown-to-html) and it worked as expected. How can I do that with Ruby.

Comment: @RonnieWiesenhower: "How can I convert the markdown to html" - huh? isn't that exactly what you do in your view? So just do it in a migration.

Comment: Yeah, ignore that last question. Thank you. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that I would backfill your DB converting all the old records to the new format.

Otherwise, make a view helper method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` something like:

```
def description_text campaign
  if campaign.created_at > Time.new(2019,3,1).in_time_zone
    campaign.product_description.html_safe
  else
    Campaign::Format campaign.product_description, {render_html: true}
  end
end
```

Note that you can probably also actually detect the HTML in the string if you'd prefer that to the time-based thing, like:

```
def description_text text
  if text.starts_with? "<html" # or whatever
    # ...
```